# How do you set up a paid subscription on a website while still adhering to App Store guidelines?

Tags: ios, mobile, app-store, subscription

I'm at the early stages of building an app, and currently our paid (subscription) version is set up through the App Store where you buy a subscription from within the app. This has a lot of issues when dealing with B2B customers because invoices are a nightmare to get right.

In any case, today I was browsing product hunt and came across [Martin](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/martin-personal-voice-ai/id6453473083), and I figured I'd try it out. What I noticed is that the app forces you to fill in an access code, which you can *only* get through their website (where you need to create an account and add payment details). Without the access code, you can only go through the onboarding and that's it.

It seems to me that this app is either bypassing the App Store guidelines (successfully?) or I'm completely confused as to how this setup works. Is there some sort of API that allows outside-of-the-store purchases but still registers with Apple so they take their cut?

I found some other related topics: [How to use iOS subscriptions with existing subscription web service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52522162/how-to-use-ios-subscriptions-with-existing-subscription-web-service) and [iOS subscription payment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73062056/ios-subscription-payment) but their solution still uses in-App purchases in some way

Can someone explain how this sort of setup would work in practice? What the proper API would be (if any)?

We tried different methods of setting up the subscription, but from our point of view the in-app subscription one is the only one that's allowed. We would prefer to create an account on our site so we have more control over the invoicing system.